# How to set different generic list value in same session in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, session

I am running one asp.net core 3.1 MVC application where i used multiple report pages.
for each report data i store in same session which contains different generic list.

e.g: Report 1 have data in List model, Which data i set in Session.Set("AllReportData", model).

for other report same like above have another generic list List model2, set in same session Session.Set("AllReportData", model2)

When user visit second report page then i used some ajax call to make this session null.

But when i used to set this session null like this: Session.Set("AllReportData", null), Then it throw error like it is asking to have the same generic list typecasting to make the session null.

But suppose in application i have more than 100 reports in that case how would i get to know about this session contains what generic list type to make it null?

Please suggest the correct approach according to the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your SessionExtension like below in asp.net core 3.1:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Text.Json;

public static class SessionExtensions
{
    public static void SetModel(this ISession session, string key, object value)
    {
        session.SetString(key, JsonSerializer.Serialize(value));
    }

    public static T GetModel<T>(this ISession session, string key)
    {
        var value = session.GetString(key);
        return value == null ? default : JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Set the session like below:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetModel("AllReportData",null);
```

Result:
[image]

**Update:**

It is impossible to invoke GetModel method without typecast.Because if you pass the complex model to session,you can only read it when you deserialize it.And the default JsonSerializer need to specify the type to tell it how to deserialize.

For your scenario,if you just want to check the session is null,you could pass an object as type:

```
var data = HttpContext.Session.GetModel<object>("AllReportData");
```

Comment: As you suggested SetModel method is working fine to make the session null, But as i can see in your attached screen shot after making session null next line GetModel method you are using type cast to check the session value which is null. But as i mentioned above like i do one ajax call to make the session null foreach report request. So there i don't know what type of typecasting this session have. If i check after make session null with GetModel without using typecast:Then i can see here variable still contain the value, Please check it and suggest.

Comment: Hi @V.Prasad,if you want to get the model in seesion without typecast,it is impossible.You need to know that the default JsonSerializer must specify a type,then you could deserialize correctly.If you just want to check the session have value or not,just pass an object like my updated answer.

Comment: Can i get it here about the session what kind of type it contains? e.g: Does this session contains User Type or Product Type. Here User or Product correlate to the model. Please suggest.